# A-orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ an n-dimensional vectorial space, with inner product $<x,y>_A=x^TAy$. Now, let $Y_1,Y_2 \ldots Y_m \in V$, which is a base for the subspace $U$ ($m<n$). How can I construct an orthogonal projector $P$ on $U$, with the defined inner product?. That is, I $<(I-P)x,Px>_A=0$ for all $x \in V$. Please, I'll appreciated any advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sketch: assemble the matrix $Y$ whose columns are the $Y_i$. Run Gram-Schmidt on this to get an orthogonal matrix $Q$ whose column space is $U$. Then the orthogonal projector is $Q Q^*$. Note that the inner product used in Gram-Schmidt and in the definition of the adjoint $Q^*$ are both the $A$-inner product, not the Euclidean one.

Comment: Thanks you very much Ian... it works!.